# Custom regex expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

Im trying to write a regex with Notepad++ so that if a line starts with a '-' the expression  appends this line to the one that immediately precedes it that also contains a colon ':'.
See example below:

```
3) In the query dialog select:
  - Query Source: 'blah' 
  - Client: 'blah'
  - From Date: 30/09/2012 00:00:00
  - To Date: 01/01/2014 00:00:00
4) Enter the query terms as follows:
  -  'URL'
  - 'Contains'
  - 'google' 

Turns into:
3) In the query dialog select: Query Source: 'blah' - Client: 'blah'  - From Date: 0/09/2012 00:00:00   - To Date: 01/01/2014 00:00:00
4) Enter the query terms as follows:  -  'URL'  - 'Contains'  - 'google'
```

Comment: `I'm trying` -- doesn't look like it thus far.

Comment: Regex don't manipulate strings... and waht have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

Find what: `(.*:.*)\R\s*-`
Replace with: `$1 -`

Comment: This will join one pair of adjacent lines. The replace will need to be multiple times to join all the lines. Four times for the example input. But I do not see any way to avoid needing to repeat, so this is a good answer.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Just click on button `Replace all`.

Comment: Just tried the replace again. Doing one **replace all** does not join the `- 'Contains'` and `- 'google'` lines to the `4) ... 'URL'` line.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Yes, you're right. But the example is contradictory with the text above. Only OP can say what behaviour he wants. The whole text will be joined in only one line.

Answer (score 0):

This works-

Regex -        `(?:\r\n)\s*([-].*?)`

Replace with - `\1`

A single Replace All does it.

Example -

```
Original text-
3) In the query dialog select:
  - Query Source: 'blah' 
  - Client: 'blah'
  - From Date: 30/09/2012 00:00:00
  - To Date: 01/01/2014 00:00:00
4) Enter the query terms as follows:
  -  'URL'
  - 'Contains'
  - 'google' 

After Replace All-

3) In the query dialog select:- Query Source: 'blah' - Client: 'blah'- From Date: 30/09/2012 00:00:00- To Date: 01/01/2014 00:00:00
4) Enter the query terms as follows:-  'URL'- 'Contains'- 'google'
```

Comment: The question asks for "contains a colon", not just lines ending with a colon. I think this answer will not join the lines `- Query Source: 'blah'` and `- Client: 'blah'`.

Comment: This will join all the lines even if it doesn't contain colon.

Comment: Yeah, but the example the OP has given,'URL'-'Contains'-'google' have also been appended. So just searched for '-' in the beginning.

Comment: The first replace will give the text `4) Enter the query terms as follows:   -  'URL'` which does not finish with a colon and so no more lines will be added, because the colon is no longer at the end of the line.

Comment: @AdrianHHH But,the beginning part of my regex is with a \r\n, so  it will match the next part containing \r\n, whitespace,capturing the content starting with'-' char and replacing the whole string sans the \r\n.